# How to support other Urls with wkwebview in react-native?

Tags: react-native, wkwebview

we are using

```
"react-native": "0.55.3",
"react-native-wkwebview-reborn": "^1.18.0",
```

we will load the WKWebView Component like this

```
                <WKWebView
                        onLoad={ this.handleWebviewLoad }
                        source={ { uri: payment.redirect_url } }
                        style={ styles.webview }
                    />
```

when payment is successful we get an redirect_target url like:

```
nativeapp://domain/buypayment/success
```

WKWebView now fails because of unsupported URL.

how can i tell WKWebView to support `nativeapp://` also instead of just `http://` and `https://`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for the other protocols in the package
`react-native-wkwebview-reborn`

In their [`RCTWKWebView.m`](https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview/blob/master/ios/RCTWKWebView/RCTWKWebView.m), it is explicitly set as

```
if ((navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame || _openNewWindowInWebView) && ([scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] || [scheme isEqualToString:@"https"])) {
    [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
  } else {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL *url = navigationAction.request.URL;
    if ([app canOpenURL:url]) {
      [app openURL:url];
    }
  }
```

*Meaning if the scheme is `http` and `https`, then it would load the request, else if it can open the `url`, it'll create a shared instance of the application and open it if it is valid.*

I don't know much of swift but this issue can be solved by adding a [`WKURLSchemeHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkurlschemehandler)
Checkout this [article](https://medium.com/glose-team/custom-scheme-handling-and-wkwebview-in-ios-11-72bc5113e344), which explains how to register and handle it.

Comment: Thank you, we will try to implement it.